# gradle task uploadArchives does not work

Tags: jenkins, gradle, artifactory

I have a gradle project executed from jenkins which should only checkout existing libraries from a repository and upload them to artifactory. The checkout is working successfully, but executing uploadArchives is throwing a MissingMethodException:

```
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.MissingMethodException: Could not find method archives() for arguments [{file=/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Libs/workspace/libphonenumber.jar, name=libphonenumber, type=jar}] on root project 'workspace'.
```

uploadArchives:

```
uploadArchives {
  println "I'm here: uploadArchives" 
  archives file: file('libphonenumber-5.7.jar'), name: 'libphonenumber', type: 'jar'
  archives file: file('log4j-1.2.17.jar'), name: 'log4j', type: 'jar'
}
```

What's the problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

That information needs to go into `artifacts { ... }`, not into `uploadArchives { ... }`.